# Is there a way to pass objects from for each loop into a swiftmailer message?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, symfony, swiftmailer

I am looping through a database and querying an array of objects, however, when i try to pass those objects from the loop into a swiftmail, i only get the last one out.   What am I missing?

I've tried to do different moving he mail object inside the loop but it sends two emails, which I don't want.  I need to somehow get all the objects save into an array and then call them into the swiftmailer.

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->select('j.fund_code', 'j.amount', 'i.source_code', 'i.keyword', 'i.created_at', 'i.status', 'g.transaction_id')
        ->join('i.gateway_response', 'g')
        ->join('i.items', 'j')
        ->Where("i.status = :status")
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('i.created_at', ':starts_at', ':ends_at'))
        ->setParameter('status', 2)
        ->setParameter('starts_at', $startsAt, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME)
        ->setParameter('ends_at', $endsAt, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
$resultCount = count($results);


if($resultCount > 0) {
    foreach($results as $holdTran) {
        $status = $holdTran['status'];
        $fundCode = $holdTran['fund_code'];
        $amount = $holdTran['amount'];
        $invoiceNumber = $holdTran['transaction_id'];
        $sourceCode = $holdTran['source_code'];
        $createdOn = $holdTran['created_at']->format('m/d/y');

    //if i vardump here, it prints all the results 

    }

    $output->writeln($resultCount . ': Transactions on Hold');

    $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
    $message = new \Swift_Message();
    $message->setSubject('Daily Giving Report')
            ->setFrom('chris2kus31@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('cmoreno@kcm.org')
            ->setContentType("text/html")
            ->setBody($this->getContainer()
            ->get('templating')
            ->render('@Giving/Default/givingReport.html.twig',
                [
                    'resultCount' => $resultCount, //only prints the last result
                    'status'=> $status,  //only prints the last result
                    'fundCode'=>$fundCode,  //only prints the last result
                    'amount'=>$amount,  //only prints the last result
                    'invoiceNumber'=>$invoiceNumber,//only prints the last result
                    'createdAt'=>$createdOn,  //only prints the last result
                    'sourceCode'=>$sourceCode  //only prints the last result
                ])

            );
    $mailer->send($message);
```

What i'd like to do is to be able to loop, get ALL the objects and pass them into the Swiftmailer.  Then, I'd like to use twig to loop and print all the results.  Such as the below but with all the results.

```
<p>Transaction {{invoice}}</p>
```

Comment: Um ... your over writing these every time `$status = ` and not using them.  So each iteration you just set a bunch of variables, then do the next iteration.  Which at the end leaves you with only the last one, because it's the last to be written to the variables, which you then use.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix but when I vardump say $status, it prints all the objects. How can i pass the array of objects to the swifmailer?

Comment: That's because you do the output inside of the loop, but you don't use any of those inside of the loop. Do the output after the loop, that's a closer refection of what you have.  Basically you reset them each time it loops, but never use them tell after the loop.  I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ah, that makes sense.   So do I need to instantiate an empty array to save the results?

Comment: Yea these should be an array `$status[] = $holdTran['status']`  Or you may be able to just do do `array_column($results, 'status')` instead of the loop.  I don't know about when you put them in the template, should they be coma separated with `implode()` or do you do something in that template etc.. I never used Twig (but I've looked its source code in the past)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this is great, thank you so much! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure...  I would post an answer, but this probably doesn't really help anyone else as it's more of a structural problem with the code then any errors (bugs).

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix , just in case someone needs it, ill post it.